# How to implement in-memory logger for last 100 log lines?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, string, logging

How to make efficient in-memory log that stores only last 100 entries and *can quickly output resulting string to TextBox (on every update)*?

I'm doing actual logging to text files using `File.AppendAllText` but want to have ability to view last entries in my application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's wrong with a simple Queue:

```
Queue<string> _items = new Queue<string>();

public void WriteLog(string value)
{
    _items.Enqueue(value);
    if(_items.Count > 100)
        _items.Dequeue();
}
```

Comment: Concatenation of all 100 strings to display in TextBox will be pretty expensive and I need it on every log update

Comment: Expensive compared to what?  and what expense is too much?  Just an opinion, but a few milliseconds shouldn't be a issue for a diagnostics tool.  If your writing 100 lines per second to your log its going to scroll too fast to see it anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/)?

And more specifically the log4net.Appender.MemoryAppender

Comment: We already have logging system hat does not provide such functionality. And we can't introduce new dependency for this single function.

Comment: You used something other than log4net?  Mind me asking what?

Answer (score 1):

Create a char array whose length is **maxloglines** * **maxlogentrywidth**. Initialize it to all blanks except a new line every **maxlogentrywidth** characters. In your logging method you offset to **maxlogentrywidth * rowIndex** and copy the N characters in the string followed by copying **maxlogentrywidth-N** spaces after that. Increment **rowIndex** by **(rowIndex+1) % maxlines**.

To output to a single string to use for a window, concatenate two strings using the [constructor that let's you index into an array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131424.aspx): `new string(chararry, curpos, len) + new string(chararray, 0, curpos-1, chararray.Lengs - curpos)` where **curpos** is **maxlogentrywidth * rowIndex**.

You'd have to add in appropriate error checking and thread-safety of course.

Comment: An alternative approach is to have a couple of buffers that can hold maxloglines; write to one of them, and any time it gets too full swap it with the other and ditch the older one.  While this approach is often not as nice as the rolling-array approach, it can be used in some cases where the rolling-array approach cannot, such as with compressed or flyweight streams.

Answer (score 0):

Possible approach:

- `ObservableCollection<string>`
- `ItemsControl` with an `ItemsTemplate` that is a borderless readonly `TextBox`
- Data binding, obviously.

Of course this has its limitations as you cannot select accross items, but there is no string concatenation in that, and using the right kind of `ItemsControl` you can make use of virtualization if needed.